# Google Maps not showing marker android

Tags: android, maps, zooming, marker

So, I tried implementing my own version of the Google Maps Activity, but to no avail. I ran into a problem with my markers not showing up, after several hours of not figuring it out, I deleted my code and copied this guys working example. Except, when I run it, it's the same issue. The map won't zoom to a specified location nor will it display map markers. That makes me believe there is an issue with the onReady section, but I'm not sure. I've tried following other stack questions/answers but I can't seem to find out what's wrong. It displays the Google Map, which I can manually zoom around in and it updates the streets and whatnot, but no markers.

[Pastebin Link to Java Code](http://pastebin.com/kr51ppBM)

XML file:
`<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.test.logintest.MapsActivity" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try by adding your markeroptions code in onMapReady() method. It might work as currently you are adding markers when there is change in location(onLocationChanged()).

```
LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOptions.position(latLng);
    markerOptions.title("Current Position");
    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
    mCurrLocationMarker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
```

Comment: So I copied your code exactly placed it in the onReady method after the permission check. I set the new LatLng to (100,100) just for testing purposes, but the marker still isn't being shown in-app.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. It was actually a mistake in my other Java file. I was trying to switch acitivies, but instead of actually switching the activity, I only changed the view.